# When confirming installation of modules, I get a server error (500)

Tags: 7

I setup my D7 websites using MAMP and since a while I failed to activate modules... Whenever I save certain modules, I get a 500-error.

[image]

I don't think it has something to do with a `memory_limit` since the error appears almost instant...

I already tried to increase the permissions (777) on the `sites` folder, but no luck there.

This is what my `apache_error.log` says:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Your server log is the best place to start, it should give you the exact exception that caused the 500

Comment: I use MAMP and I found 3 logs. `apache_error`, `mysql_error` and `php_error`. I assume it's the `apache_error`-log?

Comment: That's the one I'd check yes, you should see entries appearing any time you refresh the page if you're getting 500 errors, those should at least give you something to go on

Comment: I can't make much out of it, I'm afraid :( I included a screenshot of the results, maybe you can deduct a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoeray! I found it myself :)
It appears, you can increase the limit on multiple places like described on [this page](http://drupal.org/node/207036).

Thanks @Clive for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and in my case the error was in my.ini (using Xamp here)
the setting in question was max_allowed_packet which was too small!
changing it seems to have fixed a lot of tiny error i had been getting including the error 500 when enabling any module.

EDIT : whoa i just noticed that was from 7 years ago... not sure what the policies are about answering year old posts... crazy that I was having the "same" issue today in 2020... anyway maybe it might help someone else one day :)